# Yii - generating a URL while preserving or deleting GET parameters

Tags: php, yii

I currently have a view, manage, that lists data items. Instead of running "edit" and "add" actions with separate views, I'm having the appropriate form display inline in the page when it is needed. On the form is a "cancel" button that will hide it.

Right now I decide what, if any, form to display inline through a GET parameter called `mode`. So `/controller/manage` will display the items, while `/controller/manage?mode=edit` will display the items and show the edit form for the correct data item.

The action accepts various other GET parameters such as a date interval.

In order to activate the form, I'm generating a link to the current action with the `mode` parameter spliced in with existing parameters in `$_GET`. I'm using the following one-liner:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Edit', array_merge(array('/session/manage', 'mode' => 'edit', 'id' => 6), $_GET)); ?>
```

To implement the "cancel" link, I'm using:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Cancel', array_diff(array_merge(array('/session/manage'), $_GET), array('edit'))); ?>
```

My question is: is there a cleaner way to do this? While this *works*, it feels like a hack. I haven't found any documentation on generating URLs that include existing GET parameters. Does Yii provide a built-in method to do what I want to do? Should I re-evaluate my general approach to conditional views, which might in turn yield a cleaner solution?

Comment: I'm planing on doing something similar, but ajax based, I see no point in having all your items+form in a single view if you are loading the page on every request.

Comment: The only way I found is handing over an return_url param and parse it into your view's links.

Comment: @Asgaroth I'm working from the point of view that JavaScript/AJAX are "nice to have", ie potentially disabled, and core functionality should never have to rely on it. I try and add on AJAX functionality only after the app is fully functional without it.

Comment: @schmunk That's actually an interesting approach. I'm not sure if it's more manageable than what I'm currently doing, though. Maybe I'm just searching for a magic bullet here.

Comment: I think it would be possible to create a custom CUrlManager or CUrlRule which could provide a better createUrl() function to automate this process. May also do some validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to hold all of the most recent _GET variables in session state. Your controller would then act on that stored data and use new _GET variables to override it. Using that method, you wouldn't need to merge the existing _GET variables back into the new request. The tradeoff is that you end up having to manage that session data and handle possible special cases (like starting over with fresh state).

Another way would be to use Ajax to call an action that returns a partial view with your rendered edit form. Then your links would just need to call some javascript that does the Ajax call with the current ID and displays the returned form on the page. Your links would end up looking something like this:

`<a href="#" onclick="showEdit(6)">`

Since using Ajax wouldn't cause the page to reload, you don't need to worry about any of the _GET parameters required to show your list. And your Cancel link would become a javascript call to simply remove the edit form from the DOM. Using jQuery:

`$('#editform').remove();`

Another way to make it a little cleaner would be to encapsulate all of the `array_merge()` stuff up there into a method of a custom component or helper. Then your code could look something like:

`echo CHtml::link('Edit', URLHelper::mergeGet(array('/session/manage', 'mode' => 'edit', 'id' => 6));`

or even ecapsulate *that* in your own CHtml class:

`echo MyCHtml::link('Edit', array('/session/manage', 'mode' => 'edit', 'id' => 6));`

where `MyCHtml::link()` does everything that `CHtml::link()` does in addition to the `array_merge` stuff. MyCHtml could even extend CHtml so that it has all of CHtml's methods.

Comment: I like the last approach quite a bit, actually (Does Yii have this functionality? No? Write it yourself, now it 'does'). See my comment to schmunk above about why I'm trying to avoid AJAX if I can. Ultimately I could work AJAX into it (it would yield the cleanest, most functional result), but I'd like the core functionality to be accessible without it.

EDIT: I'm leaving this open for the time being in case there are more suggestions, but this is a nice answer with 3 very reasonable approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I added some more detail to my answer with respect to that last option.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, but I don't have enough rep to upvote, sorry.

Comment: I found this question/answer again and upvoted it for you, enjoy ;)